# Advice on mounting a servo for a nerf sentry gun

Tags: mechanism, servomotor

I am trying to make a nerf sentry gun to shoot my co workers. I am building it more or less from scratch and have come to the part where I need to come up with plans to assemble it. I am looking for advice on how to mount the mg995 servos to allow them to tilt and pan. I originally thought about having a base with a metal rod through the middle and use a gear to control the pan functionality. The idea is it would mimic a skateboard truck with a gear that would turn the rod through the middle and pivot the shooting mechanism. Another idea was to have the metal plate sit on top of the servo and use one of the attachments to attach it to the top plate. The problems I see behind this is the attachment is just a small piece of plastic and over a short period of time I could see this wearing out especially if the shooting mechanism is not centered perfectly. I also need to come up with a solution to make it tilt but I think I have an idea for this to simply use a rod with a gear to turn the pvc pipe barrel.

[Here are the servo's I am using](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D3ZXU2O)

Sorry if this is the wrong forum for the question but I was unsure where else to look for some expert advice.

**EDIT 1**

For anyone intersted I found an example of someone doing almost exactly the same thing with blueprints. I am going a slightly simpler / cheaper route and mounting the servo to the bottom of the spinning plate between the lazy susan plate I ordered. This way I don't have to buy the gears which are rather expensive and without the gears it may reduce some of the torque.

http://projectsentrygun.freeforums.org/build-progress-gladiator-ii-paintball-sentry-t130.html

Comment: Could you tell us which NERF gun you want to take, so it's easier to get an idea about a suitable construction

Comment: Sorry, I left that out. I am not using a nerf gun just the darts. I want to inflict as much pain as possible:) I am using the nerf darts but connecting it to a solenoid that uses an air compressor and in the future for portability a paintball CO2 tank. I have a relay connected to my RPI that I used to control a 12v solenoid.So the weight would be just a simple tilting pvc pipe with a hose attached for air.

Comment: If you're interested in the result rather than manufacturing your own part get a "pan and tilt bracket" for about $10 from eBay. Mine looks like this http://robokitchen.tumblr.com/post/69817774349 and takes the servos you have. 2 degrees of freedom to use the way you want, easy to attach to anything.

Comment: Thanks, that rocks!! I am going to order one of those whether I use it or not. I did come up with a solution I am going to try http://projectsentrygun.freeforums.org/build-progress-gladiator-ii-paintball-sentry-t130.html . This seems like plans for my original idea but I may simplify it by simply attaching my servo to the bottom of the plate in the middle of the lazy susan. I have some cheaper servo's and the gears may add extra torque that I can't afford.

Comment: If you're worried about wear and tear, you don't need to connect the servo directly to the plate; you could use a belt drive and a separate rotating plate to take the load off the servo.

Comment: Hi Chris. It's hard to answer this question because it's a little too general, and it's hard to discern exactly what you're asking. Perhaps you could split the question into several questions, asking for advice on various aspects in turn. Also, a diagram of what you have in mind would be helpful.